# Conduct survey - can't search to reserve after interviewing

Tags: civicampaign

I have a problem that is reproducible on the 4.6 Drupal demo site.

It has to do with the Conduct Survey screen in CiviCampaign. I cannot search for people to reserve after interviewing people.

To reproduce ....

1. Start with a Campaign and a Survey
2. Visit Conduct Survey and click Search on the Reserve Respondents tab
3. Click on the Interview Respondents tab
4. Click on the Reserve Respondents tab
5. Click Search on the Reserve Respondents tab

I expect that steps 2 and 5 should give the same response - present a list of contacts to Reserve. That happens for Step 2 but not for Step 5.

Using Firebug I see the following at Step 2 ...

```
GET  https://example.org/civicrm/campaign/vote?search=1&snippet=4&sid=99&cid=99999&qfKey=xxxxx_9999
POST https://example.org/civicrm/ajax/rest?snippet=4&className=CRM_Campaign_Page_AJAX&fnName=voterList
```

.... while at Step 5 I see only ...

```
GET  https://example.org/civicrm/campaign/vote?search=1&snippet=4&sid=99&cid=99999&qfKey=xxxxx_9999
```

The only clues I have is that the qfKey has a different value for '_9999' at the end, and I get the following error on my Javascript console at step 3 ...

TypeError: invalid 'in' operand a
https://example.org/sites/default/files/js/js_mSqimfUYz_VZK2olecI6CNgGUcoseWz2Uf-IxjMP5mA.js
Line 1079

Comment: Clue #1 - the problem doesn't occur if I have no respondents reserved

Comment: Clue #2 - the Javascript error doesn't occur if no respondents are reserved

Comment: Clue #3 the TPL file templates/CRM/Campaign/Page/Vote.tpl includes the following comment at lines 36 and 40 - "very crude refresh of tabs - fixme: use datatable native refresh method" and "fixme - can't search more than once! Uncomment this code, switching tabs gives qfkey error"

Comment: The Vote.tpl file was modified by @colemanw as part of CRM-13997. Perhaps he can shed some light?